# Create a dynamic Bootstrap toggle using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use Bootstrap's collapse functionality to create a functioning 'Show More' button on a page that I'm working on. The button should show more/hide the body text of a card description.

The problem is that the page content is being generated dynamically and I'm not sure how to use collapse in this context. I understand that I need to link the button to the content that I would like collapsed and shown.

I've tried to follow the Bootstrap documentation on collapsing elements. Unfortunately, as mentioned above, this has not yielded the expected result (Which I presume is due to the dynamic creation of my content).

HTML:

```
<pre><code>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
  scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="carsStyling.css">

  <title>Weyland's Cars</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <p>Welcome to Weyland's Cars</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="card-space" class="row">

  </div>

  <script src="cars.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
let cars = [];

function carCreator(make, model, colour, image, registrationNumber, price) {
  this.make = make;
  this.model = model;
  this.colour = colour;
  this.image = image;
  this.registrationNumber = registrationNumber;
  this.price = price;
  cars.push(this);
}

let volkswagenPolo = new carCreator("Volkswagen", "Polo", "White", "https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080", "ND 123 456", "R125 000");
let chevroletSpark = new carCreator("Chevrolet", "Spark", "Black", "https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080", "ND 654 321", "R112 000");
let renaultClio = new carCreator("Renault", "Clio", "Red", "https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080", "ND 456 789", "R225 000");
let kiaPicanto = new carCreator("Kia", "Picanto", "Grey", "https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080", "ND 987 6546", "R185 000");
let fordFiesta = new carCreator("Ford", "Fiesta", "Orange", "https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080", "ND 123 987", "R295 000");

cars.forEach(car => {

  container = document.createElement("div");
  container.className = "col-md-3";

  card = document.createElement("div");
  card.className = "card";

  image = document.createElement("img")
  image.className = "card-img-top"
  image.src = car.image;

  info = document.createElement("div");
  info.className = "card-body";

  title = document.createElement("h4")
  title.className = "card-title"
  title.innerHTML = car.make;

  details = document.createElement("p")
  details.className = "body-text"
  details.innerHTML = "Model: " + car.model + "</br>" +
                      "Colour: " + car.colour + "</br>" +
                      "Registration: " + car.registrationNumber + "</br>" +
                      "Price: " + car.price;
  details.id = "body-text-area"

  collapse = document.createElement("a")
  collapse.className = "btn btn-primary"
  collapse.innerHTML = "Show More"

  container.appendChild(card);
  card.appendChild(image);
  card.appendChild(info);
  info.appendChild(title);
  info.appendChild(details);
  info.appendChild(collapse)
  document.getElementById('card-space').appendChild(container);
})
```

Comment: please add Bootstrap reference for this function, I Don't see where it is..

Comment: @MisterJojo I'm not even sure if I'm doing this correctly but the Bootstrap classes are being generated towards the end of the JavaScript file if that's what you're referring to?

Comment: I search in Boostrap documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: @MisterJojo It's here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/

Comment: So, have you tried my answer ?, will you validate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten a lot of things in your code:

1: have a unique identifier for each 'content'

2: put the references useful for the collapse to work:
....a) details.className = 'body-text collapse';
... b) collapse.dataset.toggle = 'collapse'
...... collapse.setAttribute ('role', 'button')
...... collapse.setAttribute ('aria-expanded', 'false')
...... collapse.setAttribute ('aria-controls', 'body-text-area')

3: add the 3 JS libraries in the page!
... - jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js
... - popper.min.js
... - bootstrap.min.js

otherwise, sorry, but I can not seem to find any logic in your way of coding, so I did it in my own way, I hope it will help you

```js
class Cars {
  constructor(ref) {
    this.list = [];  // do you really need a list ?
    this.hmi_ref = ref;

    // Bootstap : container type
    this.BS = {}
    this.BS.container = document.createElement('div');
    this.BS.card      = document.createElement('div');
    this.BS.image     = document.createElement('img');
    this.BS.info      = document.createElement('div');
    this.BS.title     = document.createElement('h4');
    this.BS.details   = document.createElement('p');
    this.BS.collapse  = document.createElement('a');

    this.BS.info.appendChild( this.BS.title )
    this.BS.info.appendChild( this.BS.details )
    this.BS.info.appendChild( this.BS.collapse );
    this.BS.card.appendChild( this.BS.image );
    this.BS.card.appendChild( this.BS.info );
    this.BS.container.appendChild( this.BS.card );

    this.BS.container.className = 'col-md-3';
    this.BS.card.className      = 'card';
    this.BS.image.className     = 'card-img-top';
    this.BS.title.className     = 'card-title';
    this.BS.details.className   = 'body-text collapse';
    this.BS.collapse.className  = 'btn btn-primary';

    this.BS.collapse.dataset.toggle ='collapse'
    this.BS.collapse.textContent    = 'Show More'

    this.BS.collapse.setAttribute('role', 'button');
    this.BS.collapse.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
    this.BS.collapse.setAttribute('aria-controls', 'body-text-area');


  }
  add ( make, model, colour, image, registrationNumber, price)
  {
    this.list.push( {make, model, colour, image, registrationNumber, price } ) // for list, but why ?

    let carID = 'car_' + this.list.length;

    this.BS.image.src         = image;
    this.BS.title.textContent = make;
    this.BS.details.id        = carID;
    this.BS.details.innerHTML = `Model:${model}</br>Colour:${colour}</br>Registration:${registrationNumber}</br>Price:${price}`;
    this.BS.collapse.href     = `#${carID}`;

    let newNode = this.BS.container.cloneNode(true)

    this.hmi_ref.appendChild( newNode );

    // return carID; ?// ??
  }
}

const CardSpace = document.getElementById('card-space');

let myCars = new Cars( CardSpace );

myCars.add('Volkswagen', 'Polo', 'White', 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080', 'ND 123 456', 'R125 000');
myCars.add('Chevrolet', 'Spark', 'Black', 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080', 'ND 654 321', 'R112 000');
myCars.add('Renault', 'Clio', 'Red', 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080', 'ND 456 789', 'R225 000');
myCars.add('Kia', 'Picanto', 'Grey', 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080', 'ND 987 6546', 'R185 000');
myCars.add('Ford', 'Fiesta', 'Orange', 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080', 'ND 123 987', 'R295 000');


// console.log( myCars.list )
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p>Welcome to Weyland's Cars</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="card-space" class="row"> </div>
```